# How to get the current mouse pointer type in Java?

Tags: java, awt, mouse

I want to print the current mouse pointer type even when it is outside of the application. E.g: default, arrow, hourglass, text, resize, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Cursor.html

This is the class you have to use.

```
Cursor.getDefaultCursor().getName();
```

Comment: that will return the systems default cursor that is set in the control panel, not the one that is displayed right now...

Comment: That's just an example. Once the OP read the docs, he'll be able to get whatever he wants.

Comment: *"Once the OP read the docs"* The essential part of the answer should not rely on external documents. Instead that information should be repeated in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
java.awt.Cursor.getType()
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Cursor.html#getType--

However it would be nice if you could concretize your question so I can provide more information.
Edit:
totally forgot to reference the class holding the constants for the returned `int` value, so you do not oversee it by scrolling:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Cursor.html